# How to make submneu URL follow the tree hierarchy

Tags: php

I have a custom menu on my site and I want to make the URL follow the tree hierarchy.

**Currently What happens:**

```
www.example.com/menu-5
```

**This should be the output**

```
www.example.com/menu-2/menu-5
```

Which will mean that menu-5 is the children of menu-2. It's already added into the database.

```
/* Recursive Admin Menu */
    function recursive_list_pages( $array = array(), $content_parent = 0 ){

        if( !empty($array[$content_parent]) ){

            /* Conditional to check if the module is parent and addClass to its ul */
            $addClass = '';
            if( $content_parent == 0 ){
                $addClass = 'class="menu menu-level-' . $content_parent . '"';
            } else if( $content_parent > 0 ){
                $addClass = 'class="submenu menu-level-' . $content_parent . '"';
            }

            echo '<ul ' . $addClass . '>';
            foreach( $array[$content_parent] as $items ){

            /* Conditional to check if the module is parent and addClass, attr to its li */
            $addClassli = '';
            if( $content_parent == 0 ){
                $addClassli = 'class="menu-item menu-item-' . $items["content_id"] . '"';
            } else if( $content_parent > 0 ){
                $addClassli = 'class="submenu-item submenu-item-' . $items["content_id"] . '"';
            }

                echo '<li ' . $addClassli . '>';
                    echo '<a href="' . SITE_URL . '' . $items["content_slug"] . '">';
                    echo $items["content_title"];
                    echo '</a>';
                    recursive_list_pages( $array, $items["content_id"] );
                echo '</li>';

            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }



/* Get Menu from Database */
    function list_pages(){
        global $db;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM hpl_content WHERE content_type='pages' ORDER BY content_sort ASC";
        $query = $db->SELECT($sql);
        $array = array();
        if( $db->NUM_ROWS() > 0 ){
            $rows = $db->FETCH_ARRAY();
            foreach( $rows as $row ){ $array[$row["content_parent"]][] = $row; }
            recursive_list_pages( $array );
        }
    }
```

**Please help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like :

```
/* Recursive Admin Menu */
function recursive_list_pages( $array = array(), $content_parent = 0,$parent_slug = null){

    if( !empty($array[$content_parent]) ){

        /* Conditional to check if the module is parent and addClass to its ul */
        $addClass = '';
        if( $content_parent == 0 ){
            $addClass = 'class="menu menu-level-' . $content_parent . '"';
        } else if( $content_parent > 0 ){
            $addClass = 'class="submenu menu-level-' . $content_parent . '"';
        }

        echo '<ul ' . $addClass . '>';
        foreach( $array[$content_parent] as $items ){

        /* Conditional to check if the module is parent and addClass, attr to its li */
        $addClassli = '';
        if( $content_parent == 0 ){
            $addClassli = 'class="menu-item menu-item-' . $items["content_id"] . '"';
        } else if( $content_parent > 0 ){
            $addClassli = 'class="submenu-item submenu-item-' . $items["content_id"] . '"';
        }

            echo '<li ' . $addClassli . '>';
            if(is_null($parent_slug)) {
                echo '<a href="' . SITE_URL . $items["content_slug"] . '">';
            } else {
                echo '<a href="' . SITE_URL . $parent_slug . '/' . $items["content_slug"] . '">';
            }

                echo $items["content_title"];
                echo '</a>';
                recursive_list_pages( $array, $items["content_id"], $items['content_slug']);
            echo '</li>';

        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

If you didn't order your items by the parent id (so that the result is : parent 1, first child of parent 1, second child of parent 1, parent 2, first child of parent 2 etc), I think you should.

But basically you need to pass the parent's slug and for the child links append the parent slug before their own slug.